# Tumblr vs other web frameworks

Tags: tumblr

I'm a new user to [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/) and I was amazed by the quantity of functions and its level of integration with main social networks.

What was the best to me, was the possibility of editing the code of the pages directly from the site, possibibly inserting JavaScript.

However now I have to create a site, not a blog.

So my question is: are there comparable *free* services focused on website creation, which allows the choosing and modification of the themes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call Tumblr a web framework. It's a social blogging platform that allows customization through an templating engine. You **can not** insert any JavaScript. They allow you to call certain approved js files like Twitter’s widget.js but that's about it.

Basically you have control of how your content is displayed via HTML and some custom CSS along pre enabled social sharing.

No hosted platform is going to allow you full control. [WordPress.com](http://wordpress.com) would be better for creating a website. Your best bet is to self host and use a CMS to build your site.